# checking out convert option available for ubuntu

Tags: convert

I need to check out whether my linux system installation have "convert" command available. Is there a command to control this situation?

Comment: Maybe you can look at this forum thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: `which convert`

Comment: check the output of `type -a convert`

Comment: how can I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a command is available

```
which <command>
```

In your case

```
which convert
```

Or use locate

```
sudo updatedb #necessary if you recently installed
locate convert
```

convert is a part of imagemagick , so to install

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: [`which` is not a good solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/3789550)..

Comment: @heemayl - why not ? convert is a bit strange as it is a part of imagemagik

Comment: at the very least level, why would you fork an external process that `type` or `hash` can do easily....the link has farther explanations....

Comment: @heemayl - that link seems a little off topic to say the least (running which in scripts), not to mention somewhat opinionated and even inaccurate. With modern computers launching a separate process is rather trivial (0.012 seconds, really ?) and which does set an exit status.